# What is the space complexity of my python function?

Tags: python, space-complexity

Can someone tell me what the space complexity for this python function is?
I believe it is O(1) but my friends are telling me that this is O(N).

Reason why they are saying O(N):
You are creating a new 'a' in every iteration of the for loop.

Reason why I am saying O(1):You make a new 'a' every time you iterate and dump out the old 'a'.

```
def hello(n):
  for i in range(n):
    a = 10
```

Would the space complexity be the same if this is pseudo code?

Comment: in Python 3 it is O(1), since `range` will take constant space, in Python 2, it is O(n) since range will take O(n) space. But you are correct, simply reassigning to `a` will take constant space. In Python 2, use `xrange` for constant-space

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*a* is just a variable, and here you assign a with integer value, for this point, the space complexity is O(1).

But I think the key to measure is in `for i in range(n)` statement.

In *python2*, because `range(n)` will create a list with n element, so the space complexity is O(n).

In *python3*, `range(n)` will return an iterator(without creating the whole n-length list), so the space complexity is O(1).

Comment: What if the value of 'a' changes after every iteration of the for loop? Does the space complexity remain the same?